# $safeprojectname$ throwing errors in VSIX Package

Tags: c#, vsix, project-template

I'm attempting to create a VSIX package to deploy for some common application layouts that I use, however when I create the Project Template then put the template files in my VSIX package and build it, I get a lot of `Unexpected character '$'` messages in some of my C# classes on the namespace. According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eehb4faa.aspx), this should be the proper format.

This is one of the classes throwing the error

```
using System.Web.Optimization;

namespace $safeprojectname$ {
    public class BundleConfig {
        public static void Register(BundleCollection bundles) {
            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/styles/site")
                .IncludeDirectory("~/assets/styles", "*.css"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/scripts/libs")
                .IncludeDirectory("~/assets/libs/jquery", "*.js")
                .IncludeDirectory("~/assets/libs/bootstrap", "*.js")
                .Include("~/assets/libs/angular/angular.js")
                .Include("~/assets/libs/angular/angular-sanitize.js")
                .Include("~/assets/libs/angular/angular-animate.js")
                .IncludeDirectory("~/assets/libs/angular-ui", "*.js")
                .IncludeDirectory("~/assets/scripts", "*.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/scripts/app")
                //.IncludeDirectory("~/common/directives", "*.js")
                //.IncludeDirectory("~/common/filters", "*.js")
                //.IncludeDirectory("~/common/services", "*.js")
                .Include("~/app/home/app.home.js")
                .IncludeDirectory("~/app/home/controllers", "*.js")
                .Include("~/app/app.js"));
        }
    }
}
```

I checked my vstemplate file and this is what it has for that file/folder

```
<Folder Name="startup" TargetFolderName="startup">
    <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="BundleConfig.cs">BundleConfig.cs</ProjectItem>
    <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="WebApiConfig.cs">WebApiConfig.cs</ProjectItem>
</Folder>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The class that gives you an error, is a **template content**. The idea of template content is to be a simple "txt" file, which will be later processed by vsix infrastructure to replace all the parameters, such as `$safeprojectname$`.

What you're doing right now, is that you're trying to compile your class, but you should not do it. Click on that file, "Build Action -> None".

[image]

Comment: I am still getting same error with global.asax file and controllers.

Comment: Setting build action to None does unfortunately not help in VS 2017 (15.9.1). It build everything correctly and the extension works, but the error are shown which is quite confusing